# What is the best way to store shared data in SPA(Single Page Application)?

Tags: html, single-page-application

What is the best way to store shared data in SPA(Single Page Application)?

- data size:1MB
- data update interval: a day

  1. javascript object
  2. HTML5 web storage
  3. HTML5 web SQL
  4. others

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: Roberts link is an excellent reference - Thanks Rob!